# Programmatically find main() method in collection of classes

Tags: java, class, jar, javac, program-entry-point

I am working on a project that needs to take an arbitrary number of java files, compile them, jar them, then run them. The problem I'm facing is this: Which class do we run? Is it possible to find the entry point in a set of classes?

I'm willing to make the assumption that the given files will have only one entry point.

Here is what I've considered so far:

- Add a helper class to every jar that uses reflection to find the class with main(). To run the jar, call that helper class.
- Make the user name their main() class "Main", or something to that effect.

Is there a good way to go about this? This software is meant for students and novice programmers, so I am willing to sacrifice robustness for simplicity.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just make them provide a manifest in the JAR file?

Comment: I suppose I could. I'm just hesitant to add any complexity to the system. Think middle schoolers. I will definitely do this if there isn't a good alternative.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Manifest is definitely the best way, but your suggestion in the question about naming their main class a certain way might also help you teach them convention vs. configuration, which is a useful thing to know about.

Comment: This is potentially a lot of work, but it's interesting. I'd look at how Spring does its component scanning (start with `org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider#findCandidateComponents`), but instead of annotations I'd look for method main. They use ASM for class parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea off the top of my head could be a custom annotation.  It's a little more robust than a naming convention, but easier than creating a manifest file.

Something like:

```
@MainClass
public class MyClass {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Your tool could scan classes for the annotation.

Comment: I'd upgrade this idea to a solution where you don't make the student write the `public static void main` -- in all probability they are not handling command-line args, anyway. Set a requirement that any public no-arg method may be marked with the @EntryPoint annotation, and write your own, reused class that has the low-level entry point (`public static void main`). An even simpler approach would be to use a naming convention for the method since using an annotation causes a dependency to a JAR -- another obstacle.

Comment: I think I will pursue Marko's idea further. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know which class contains the main() is to provide a manifest in the JAR file which calls out the main class.

However your suggestion in the question about naming their main class a certain way might also help you teach them convention vs. configuration, which is a useful thing to know about.